# NodeJS + http-proxy - Object has no method 'resume'

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, comet, http-proxy

The strange thing about this problem is that I had a working example (albeit with no data being transferred post-handshake) before I went away from my desk, and now I can't seem to get this working properly, despite reverting the few minor changes I made.

I'm using NodeJS + the http-proxy module to proxy requests for .html files to Apache, and all other requests are being processed by NodeJS.

Here's my server.js code:

```
CometServer = (function() {

  var instance;

  function __construct() {

    var apachePort = 3000;
    var nodeJsPort = 3001;
    var apacheHost = 'localhost';
    var nodeJsHost = 'localhost';
    var httpProxy = require('/root/node_modules/http-proxy');
    var io = require('/root/node_modules/socket.io');
    var fs = require('/root/node/lib/fs');
    var path = require('/root/node/lib/path');
    var url = require('/root/node/lib/url');
    var apacheUrls = [
      /.*\.html/,
      /^\/$/
    ];

    function proxyRequests(request, response, proxy) {

      // Check if the URL is a comet request or not.
      var shouldProxy = apacheUrls.some(function(requestUrl) {
        return requestUrl.test(request.url);
      });

      // If 'request.url' matches any of the 'apacheUrls' then proxy to Apache.
      if (shouldProxy) {

        return proxy.proxyRequest(request, response, {
          host: apacheHost,
          port: apachePort
        });

      }

      // Not proxied to Apache; this is a comet request and should be processed by NodeJS.
      return handleUnproxiedRequests(request, response);

    }

    function handleUnproxiedRequests(request, response) {
      var uri = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
      var filePath = path.join(process.cwd(), '..', uri);

      var extname = path.extname(filePath);
      var contentType = 'text/javascript';

      path.exists(filePath, function(exists) {
        if (exists) {
          var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
          fileStream.on('data', function (data) {
            response.writeHead(200, {
              'Content-Type': contentType
            });
            response.write(data);
            response.end();
          });
        }
        else {
          response.writeHead(404);
          response.end();
        }
      });
      return;
    }

    function bootstrap() {

      // Create a http proxy server and use the 'proxy' conditionally inside the request handler.
      var server = httpProxy.createServer(nodeJsPort, nodeJsHost, {
        target: {
          host: nodeJsHost,
          port: nodeJsPort
        }
      }, proxyRequests);

      // Get the http proxy server to listen to a port.
      server.listen(nodeJsPort);

      // Get socket.io to listen to the proxy server.
      var listener = io.listen(server);

      var something = listener.on('connection', function(socket) {
        console.log('socket connected');
        socket.on('handshake', function(pid) {
          console.log('socket? ' + pid);
        })
      });

    }

    // Bootstrap server.
    bootstrap();

    return { }

  }

  return {
    getInstance: function() {
      // Instantiate only if the instance doesn't already exist.
      if (!instance) {
        instance = __construct();
      }
      return instance;
    }
  }
})();

// Initialize the comet server.
CometServer.getInstance();
```

And the client side js:

```
var socket = io.connect();
console.log('Connected');
socket.on('connect', function(data) {
  console.log('Sending handshake');
  socket.emit('handshake', 1);
});
```

Please note that this code is a little messy at the moment as it's in very early stages of production. However, feel free to critique it if you like, if you think there's something I could/should be doing in a different way.

Here's the error message I receive when I try to access a .html page:

```
/root/node_modules/http-proxy/lib/node-http-proxy/http-proxy.js:334
      ? buffer.resume()
           ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'resume'
    at [object Function].proxyRequest (/root/node_modules/http-proxy/lib/node-http-proxy/http-proxy.js:334:16)
    at proxyRequests (/var/www/html/Comet/server.js:139:22)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/root/node_modules/http-proxy/lib/node-http-proxy.js:321:7)
    at Manager.handleRequest (/root/node_modules/socket.io/lib/manager.js:531:28)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/root/node_modules/socket.io/lib/manager.js:112:10)
    at Server.emit (events.js:70:17)
    at HTTPParser.onIncoming (http.js:1479:12)
    at HTTPParser.onHeadersComplete (http.js:102:31)
    at Socket.ondata (http.js:1375:22)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:334:27)
```

From what I've read, it looks like the data is buffered rather than streamed, but I don't really have any idea how to fix this as I'm very new to the API (this is my first NodeJS project).

Any help would be appreciated, as I've been banging my head against a brick wall with this for quite a while now.

Comment: I've also tried deliberately passing a buffer to the proxyRequest: as below:

    var buffer = httpProxy.buffer(request);

    return proxy.proxyRequest(request, response, {
      port: apachePort,
      host: apacheHost,
      buffer: buffer
    });

Unfortunately, I still end up with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, it seems that some of the arguments passed into the createServer method were extraneous - I fixed the issue with the following:

```
var server = httpProxy.createServer(proxyRequests);
```

I'm not entirely sure why this worked, and why my previous example stopped working after originally running correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are experiencing this issue:
https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/1956